# How to debug this c code

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, free

see video - https://youtu.be/kXXpj1ruE0o

Okay, i am writing this program where it prints last n lines of input. n is command line argument, default is 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[500];
int pos = 0;

void copy(char* tailed[], int n){

    if(pos == n){

        // moving contents of array to one position back

        for(int i=0; i<pos-1; i++)
            tailed[i] = tailed[i+1];
        //free(tailed[pos-1]); not working
        pos--;
    }
    tailed[pos++] = strcpy(malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char)), line);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc > 2){
        printf("[*]Error");
        return 0;
    }

    int n = argc==2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 10, c;
    char* tailed[n];

    while(scanf("%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF){
        copy(tailed, n);            
    }

    for(int i=0; i<pos; i++)
        printf("%s\n", tailed[i]);
}
```

This code is working fine and printing the last n lines. But when i use the free(tailed[pos-1]), the program give wrong answer.

code explanation ..

scanf() takes input and stores in character array line. if pos is less than n the line is copied to new memory created by malloc and pointer is stored in tailed array.

if pos variable becomes greater than n, the contents of array are moved to one position back and last element is cleared using free().

if i don't use free(), the program gives correct output but doesn't when used.

Comment: The easy response is to tell you to look at a debugger and step through your code manually. It's a very useful skill, you should try it.

Comment: Small thing I noticed: You're declaring an int, `c`, then never using it.

Comment: you seem to free some stuff before dinamically allocating it... this could be your problem? in Copy function, you use free before malloc, probably.

Comment: @SMFSW no, free is always used after malloc.

Comment: how about we start by including proper headers (you're missing `stdio.h`, and it is required for `printf`.

Comment: @ryyker no. when i free the previously allocated pointer, i get wrong output.

Comment: @WhozCraig i have included..

Comment: `strlen(...)` returns count of characters currently occupying a buffer, but does not include the `\0` character.  If you are allocating memory for a new buffer, that needs to be big enough to contain the same size string, then you need to include `+1` to size in malloc statement to allow for NULL termination.  Always.

Comment: @Atul You're freeing the wrong string. The point of your loop is to shift *down* the entries. The one being tossed is the FIRST string, not the last. you should `free(tailed[0])` before your shift loop, then free *nothing* afterward.

Comment: @ryyker i see, but that doesn't fixes the issue.. check video i added link

Comment: @WhozCraig... thank you. i didn't see that.

Comment: @Atul it's pretty important, as it leaves your array filled with pointers to now-freed strings as you enter more and more, and the allocator is free to reuse that memory (and probably does).

Comment: @ryyker thank you, you are also correct. But i was clearing the wrong string, thats why i was getting wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least you may be invoking *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* by creating a buffer too short to accept what is subsequently written to it.

The line:

```
tailed[pos++] = strcpy(malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char)), line);
```

besides being very unconventional, is shorting the target buffer by 1, and should be:

```
tailed[pos++] = strcpy(malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char))+1, line);
                                                          ^^
```

strlen(...) returns count of characters currently occupying a buffer, but does not include the \0 character. If you are allocating memory for a new buffer, that needs to be big enough to contain the same size string, then you need to include +1 to size in malloc statement to allow for NULL termination. Always.

By way of illustration, when I run your original code on my system, I get this run-time indication:

[image]

Once I add the `+1`, it works normally, without any run-time errors.

By the way, typing *[list of good C debuggers](https://www.google.com/#q=List+of+good+C+debuggers&*)* into Google yields pretty good results...  [image]

Answer (score -1):

i Was clearing the wrong string. free(tailed[0]) is working.